# Type mismatch error for large array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am getting this VBA error of Type Mismatch on Line 3, but it works very well if the array is shorter like `A3:A52`. Is it because there is limited on array size?

```
Dim varry() As Variant
varry = [A2:A520000&G2:G520000]
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Application.Match(CLng(DateValue("5/14/2013")) & "YUM", varry, 1) & " " & Timer - t
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
DoEvents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a limitation of `Application.Match` when passing an `Array`.  The max size array it will handle is 65536 long.

If you pass a `Range`, it will handle longer data: eg

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = [A1:A520000]
result = Application.Match(YourSearchTerm, r, 1)
```

I know, not a complete solution for your case, given you are concatenating two ranges into the array, but you may be able to devise a solution refactoring the wider application of your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to just set a cell in an unused column of the table equal to the maximum value of the column of interest then just search on that limited range:

```
Dim Max_date As Date
Dim daterange As Range
Set daterange = Range("t2:t2")
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(daterange)
MsgBox Max_date
```

Where cell t2=max(column of interest)

That gets around the array length limitation. In my case I set t2=max(c2:c500000)